# How to use css selector in Golang

Tags: go, goquery

In Ruby, I have something like `contents = html_doc.css("img + a")`. How would I do this in Go?

I am trying to use Goquery but I am unsure of how to convert it. Specifically, I tried doc.find("img") but it doesn't find anything for some reason

Edit: Here is the HTTP I'm trying to parse through:

```
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="convobot-main/">convobot-main/</a>                    2022-01-27 13:55    -
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="matlab/">matlab/</a>                           2022-01-31 11:58    -
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="test/">test/</a>                             2022-01-27 13:52    -
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="test3%20-%20Copy/">test3 - Copy/</a>                     2022-02-09 15:09    -
<img src="/icons/folder.gif" alt="[DIR]"> <a href="test3/">test3/</a>                            2022-02-09 10:47    -
<img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"> <a href="Quadractic.mlx">Quadractic.mlx</a>                    2022-01-21 15:02  3.3K
</pre>
```

I am looking to get the file names like Quadractic.mlx

Comment: Edit the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Can check this https://github.com/ericchiang/css

Comment: @Zombo yea I added the HTTP that I'm trying to parse through if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: Do you want all images and links? What do you want to parse from HTML?

Comment: @Jens I want the <a ref> that comes right after the img tag. I probably should expand the http, but there are some case where there are multiple <a href> after an img tag

Comment: What are the boundaries? Links between two different images `<img/><a></a><img/>`? Because every link after an image is kind of unbounded? Weird HTML structure.

Comment: I guess you should provide proper HTML example with the exact result you expect. Otherwise, this will be hard to understand.

Comment: @Henry Edit the question to show the code that you tried. Something like https://go.dev/play/p/UeWTzaSgy7A